# Populating access table from form multi-record textbox

Tags: ms-access, vba

I am trying to use this code to pick comma seperated numbers from ExcUID text box of form and then feed them into tblExcIndivList table.

However what I am trying to do it to split ex: 123,1213 into lines and put them in seperate rows of UID column of tblExcIndivList table but it gets saved as 1231213 in the same cell.

```
Sub Upd_UID()
Dim var As Variant
Dim i As Long

var = Split(Forms.Agen_Report.ExcUID.Value, vbNewLine)
CurrentDb.Execute "DELETE * FROM tblExcIndivList;", dbFailOnError
For i = 0 To UBound(var)
    CurrentDb.Execute Replace("INSERT INTO tblExcIndivList ( UID ) VALUES ( '@V' );", "@V", var(i)), dbFailOnError
Next i
End Sub
```

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not splitting correctly your string, you say it is comma-separated (i.e. `123,1213`) and try to split it with `vbNewLine`. You should specify the comma as separator:

```
var = Split(Forms.Agen_Report.ExcUID.Value, ",")
```

This will get you past this error and split correctly the input. However I cant make sure whether your query is well-formed.

Comment: Thanks @A.S.H,

What a silly mistake I made, but you saved me.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need something like this.

```
Option Explicit

Dim aCell As Range

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    '~~> Change Sheet1 to the relevant sheet name
    '~~> Change A1:E1 to the relevant range
    For Each aCell In ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:E1")
        If InStr(1, aCell.Value, ",") Then _
        ComboBox1.AddItem Split(aCell.Value, ",")(0)
    Next aCell

    '~~> Remove duplicates
    RemoveDuplicates ComboBox1
End Sub

Private Sub ComboBox1_Click()
    Dim tmpStr As String

    ComboBox2.Clear

    For Each aCell In ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:E1")
        If InStr(1, aCell.Value, ",") Then _
        tmpStr = Split(aCell.Value, ",")(0)

        If Trim(ComboBox1.Value) = Trim(tmpStr) Then _
        ComboBox2.AddItem aCell.Value
    Next aCell
End Sub

'~~> Procedure to remove duplicates
Private Sub RemoveDuplicates(cmb As ComboBox)
    Dim a As Integer, b As Integer, c As Integer

    a = cmb.ListCount - 1
    Do While a >= 0
        For b = a - 1 To 0 Step -1
            If cmb.List(b) = cmb.List(a) Then
                cmb.RemoveItem b
                a = a - 1
            End If
        Next b
        a = a - 1
    Loop
End Sub
```